# Make [azuread] a synonym of [azure-active-directory]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are 2 tags for general Microsoft Azure Active Directory posts:
[azuread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azuread) and [azure-active-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-active-directory).

I would like to make [azure-active-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-active-directory) the master tag, and have [azuread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azuread) be a synonym to that master tag.